# Are there any flights which fly above the Bermuda Triangle?

Tags: air-travel, adventure, bermuda-triangle

The Bermuda Triangle is a mysterious place on earth where hundreds of ships and flights have reportedly gone missing.

Do flights and ships still currently travel through the Bermuda Triangle region?

Comment: While 'do flights travel here' is still a valid and interesting question, it's worth noting that it's not really mysterious - numbers have been exaggerated, ships lost outside the triangle have been attributed to the triangle, and so on (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bermuda_Triangle#/Criticism_of_the_concept)

Comment: How would flights get to the airports located inside the Bermuda Triangle if they didn't travel through it?

Comment: _Inside bermuda triangle_ google return nothing?

Comment: Map the antipodes of the Bermuda Triangle into the Southern Hemisphere and see what you get!!! People fly there. Most come back. BUT some of the weirdest and most mysterious things on earth inhabit that area. Fair Dinkum, Cobber!!!

Comment: The biggest mystery is why the aliens don't steal the Bermuda water :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epGgNU5yumQ

Comment: @MarkMayo: "numbers have been exaggerated" - "The Bermuda Triangle has a following of people who try to cover up and play down its true mysterious properties ..." (sorry, just kidding, could not resist ;) )

Comment: @MarkMayo: On a more serious note: "While 'do flights travel here' is still a valid and interesting question" - well, given that [there isn't even a general consensus about what constitutes the Bermuda Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bermuda_Triangle#Triangle_area), I am not so sure the question is valid in the first place.

Comment: @SagarV: Really? I get "about 3,600,000 results".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - the fact that there's no consensus about what constitutes the Bermuda Triangle **PROVES THAT THERE'S A CONSPIRACY AT WORK**!!!! ***SHOCKING!!!!***  :-)

Comment: Although there is a certain urge in me to post a funny or sarcastic answer or comment, I think it's best to point out that planes gone missing a big news in the age of 911. The first suspects would always be terrorist followed be sweeping ocean floors and locating the black box. I would like to invite you to tell us about *any* incident like this in the past twenty years that occurred in the Bermuda Triangle.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The premise of your question is incorrect.  The Bermuda Triangle is not mysterious.  From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bermuda_Triangle):

> Most reputable sources dismiss the idea that there is any mystery. The vicinity of the Bermuda Triangle is one of the most heavily traveled shipping lanes in the world, with ships frequently crossing through it for ports in the Americas, Europe, and the Caribbean islands. Cruise ships and pleasure craft regularly sail through the region, and commercial and private aircraft routinely fly over it.

From personal experience, I can say that I have flown through the area several times without incident.

The article also notes that given the proximity of the area to the Atlantic hurricane zone, the number of craft lost in the area is "neither disproportionate, unlikely, nor mysterious."  It also notes that insurers do not charge higher premiums for vessels traveling in the area.

Comment: Seconding this answer. I have flown across it too. If you want to travel the "triangle" yourself, there are dozens of flights every day. Take any flight from the US East Coast to Puerto Rico (e.g. JFK->SJU) or go to Jamaica from anywhere in Europe.

Comment: "The vicinity of the Bermuda Triangle is one of the most heavily traveled shipping lanes in the world" and therefore the most of the incidents in raw numbers happen there. Is all about statistic. The interesting number would be incidents/travel through.

Comment: ' It also notes that insurers do not charge higher premiums for vessels traveling in the area' Always a good benchmark of risk. If insurers think something is going to cost them money you can guarantee they'll be compensating for it!

Comment: @Braiam exactly. It's also why there are more car crashes, on average, in Manhattan than in a Manhattan-sized chunk of western Nebraska.

Answer (score 69):

At this moment, [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/24.68,-74.69/6) shows more than 30 commercial flights in the area, and that's likely true at almost any time of the day. I'm betting most will survive ;)

[image]

Comment: This image would be much more useful if the triangle was marked in it.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann in red and hand draw.

Comment: Done, as per @PaŭloEbermann and Braiam requests. Note, as [Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bermuda_Triangle), that the Bermuda Triangle is a *loosely defined region*.

Comment: Is this from a website, like https://www.flightradar24.com/ ? Or one of the other 4 or 5 sites with "flight" and "radar" in their names? Plain http://www.flightradar.org/ ? A link in the answer would be nice, save others from asking Mr.DuckDuckGo or Mr.Google

Comment: @Xen2050: Done. It looks like I took a picture at a quiet time, as there are way more planes there right now.

Answer (score 5):

I was stationed in the bahamas at a base that is situated well inside the "Triangle" in the NAVY. I was there for 10 years, and not a single incident involving military or any other ship or air craft in that time.

Answer (score 4):

Others have covered the Northern hemisphere. But, what about the southern hemisphere equivalent?

Map the antipodes of the Bermuda Triangle into the Southern Hemisphere and see what you get!!! People fly there. Most come back...

BUT some of the weirdest and most mysterious things on earth inhabit that area. Fair Dinkum, Cobber!!!  Further East in the Southern hemisphere version even weirder things happen

[image]

Comment: The southern hemisphere is a really weird place, with everyone upside down ;)

Comment: ɐᴉlɐɹʇsn∀ :uoᴉʇnɐƆ

Comment: I sense an entirely novel MH370 theory in the making ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Somewhere between Uluru & Alice perhaps. Maybe at the culturally off limits to "most" upper end of kings or the similarly proscribed "Olgas". Too far south probably. Maybe Birdsville?

Comment: Wow - 8 upvotes to offset the 11 upvotes. Apparently the Bermuda Triangle's mysterious is worthy of serious discussion, but contrasting examples that make a point are verboten :-). | But, maybe just a lack of antipodean humour ? :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: ¿ sǝʇoʌdn 8

Comment: @MSalters, I think it's 13 upvotes and sǝʇoʌdn 8.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: I think it's probably more that this doesn't answer the question, nor attempt to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (1) Can it be ? !!! :-) (2) Isn't that well correlated with a lack of antipodean humour ? [ :-) :-) ....]