# Is it safe to fly from Miami to Puerto Rico due to the Bermuda Triangle?

Tags: air-travel, safety, puerto-rico, miami, bermuda-triangle

We are planning a trip from Miami to Puerto Rico in January 2018 but we are concerned about safety as the flight path lies within the Bermuda Triangle.

What can you tell me about the safety of flights within this triangle?

Comment: Consider, depending on the interpretation of the Bermuda Triangle, on any given day >50% of all movements in and out of Miami International Airport and Ft. Lauderdale International Airport passes through the BT with no consideration.  Myself hundreds of times and I'm still here ;)

Comment: [Right now](https://www.flightradar24.com/25.81,-71.97/6)

Comment: @Johns-305 How do you know that you weren't transported to an alternate reality the first time you passed through it, and this is all a dream?

Comment: @Doc Realistically, only about 12 of the infinite parallel universes is worth visiting so I don't bother anymore...unless it's the one where I'm Admiral Adama. ;)

Comment: See also [Are there any flights that fly above the Bermuda triangle?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89252/19400)

Answer (score 14):

The 'Bermuda Triangle' is an urban legend, nothing more. (just gooogle it)

In addition, the flight path is nowhere near the triangle, which is much further north. You don't need to be concerned at all.

Comment: In addition, statistics and data on flights around the Bermuda Triangle are extensive, due to the public interest around the legend, so you could possibly have greater confidence in the safety record there than in some other areas :-)

Comment: I once got a nasty earache by flying through the Bermuda Triangle, but that was due to the decision to catch a flight out of San Juan while I had a cold. Perfectly normal occurrence that had nothing to do with geography.

Answer (score 3):

According to the US Coast Guard, [the Bermuda Triangle is not a real phenomenon](https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/research/library/bibliographies/bermuda-triangle-selective-bibliography.html). They claim that the agency "does not recognize the existence of the so-called Bermuda Triangle as a geographic area of specific hazard to ships or planes".

The National Oceanographic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) of the USA [states](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/bermudatri.html):

> The U.S. Navy and U.S. Coast Guard contend that there are no supernatural explanations for disasters at sea.  Their experience suggests that the combined forces of nature and human fallibility outdo even the most incredulous science fiction. They add that no official maps exist that delineate the boundaries of the Bermuda Triangle. The U. S. Board of Geographic Names does not recognize the Bermuda Triangle as an official name and does not maintain an official file on the area.